# How to find element on bank web site

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer

The web url is 
[CCB bank login page](https://ibsbjstar.ccb.com.cn/CCBIS/V6/common/login.jsp?UDC_CUSTOMER_ID=&UDC_CUSTOMER_NAME=&UDC_COOKIE=bfc8f8dfe760d0deSksRDOP5e91pieyJPx2G1587538902715Idk1KIX010H62YAcjp1y750fedb4b839e12db4901f58ad386407&UDC_SESSION_ID=jEzm3Fmp62rCHB4fe86a605ee73-20200422150142)

[image: This the element I need to Locate]

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='data_money']")
```

but I can't find any element.
I've try switch to frame before find element by

```
driver.switch_to_frame
```

but still can't find any element, Any one can help me to resolve this issue?
My code as blew

```
driver = webdriver.Ie()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(8)
driver.get(CCB)
time.sleep(2)
driver.switch_to_frame
driver.switch_to_frame(0)
driver.find_element_by_name("USERID").send_keys(user_id)
driver.find_element_by_name("LOGPASS").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_id("loginButton").click()
time.sleep(5)
dm_ret = dm.FindPic(0,0,2000,2000,"d:\Test_Code\Talk_later.bmp","303030",0.9,0,intX,intY)
if dm_ret[1] > 0 and dm_ret[2] > 0 :
    print("PIC found")
    dm.moveto(dm_ret[1]+24, dm_ret[2]+12)
    dm.leftclick()
else :
    print("PIC not found")
    time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class='data_money']")
```

Comment: Please consider adding a url to the website and also your full code, so as we can answer you properly.

Comment: @Abhaysalvi I can add the url but login require USB key. So I think if you don't have that you can't login.

Comment: Umm.. so how can I help you in that case? Did you face any errors? Also can you show your code?

Comment: @Abhaysalvi I'm face the error that "can't find any element" with find element

Comment: Okay. So it's a bit code related problem. Add your code to your question, and replace your login credentials with any other characters.

Comment: @Abhaysalvi I've update my code already.

Comment: Try copying full XPATH instead... And also put `time.sleep(3)` before it.

Comment: @Abhaysalvi I'm test in python commend line, so time.sleep is not issue, cause the element are present when I send find element code.

Comment: @Abhaysalvi  Message: Unable to find element with xpath == /html/body/div/div/div/div/iframe/html/body/div/form/div/div/div/div/div/div/h3/p.font_money/span.data_money/text

Comment: Sorry. See I can help this much only . I need to interact with any website personally on my PC if I need to scrape one, but since I can't log in to the page I can't help you. But I just wanna ask you one question. Are you scraping that site as a code related exercise or do you want the site's data anyhow? In that case you can try using https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spider-a-smart-web-scrapi/hhblpocflefpmmfibmajdfcjdkeafpen this extension.

Comment: @Abhaysalvi do you install google remote desktop ? I can enable remote desktop and give you support code to you, that you can remote control my NB.

Comment: @Abhaysalvi I want to get balance from this web site. and this web site only can login with IE.

Comment: Please check your code, whether this element is inside a IFrame control? If it's located in the iframe control, you should find the iframe control first, then find that element. Besides, try to find the element based on the Class and Name property.

Comment: Maybe your quotation is wrong: "//span[@class='data_money']"  instead of '//span[@class='data_money']"

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT I've try both find element by class and name also,but still can't fine element. I've try switch to iframe that I've mention in my question, is that you say "find frame control"?

Comment: @Mace It is my typo, I'll correct it. Thanks.

Comment: Try to use F12 developer tools to check the DOM elements, whether there has multiple iframe tag, whether you switch to correct iframe tag. Here is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58596564/) about find element from iframe tag, you could refer to it.